# Test cases won't work when implementing my own stack

Tags: java, testing, junit, stack

So our homework was to implement a stack on our won and then write test cases for it.
This is the stack:

```
    import java.util.Vector;

class Stack<T> extends Vector<T> {
    private Vector<T> stack;

    Stack() {
        stack = new Vector<T>();
    }

    // returns false or true, given the stack is empty or not.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stack.size() == 0;
    }

    //returns the top element of the stack without removing it.
    public T peek() {
        return stack.get(stack.size()-1);
    }

    //puts a new element to the top of the stack
    public void push(T element) {
        stack.add(element);
    }

    //returns and removes the top element of the stack
    public T pop() {
        return stack.get(stack.size()-1);
    }
}
```

And this is my test class so far.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class StackTest {

    @Test
    void isEmpty() {
        stack s = new stack<Integer>;
        assertEquals(true, s.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    void peek() {
        Stack t = new Stack(1);
    }

    @Test
    void push() {
    }

    @Test
    void pop() {
    }

}
```

I am really having trouble figuring out what is wrong with the first two test methods. Does anybody else have an idea?

Comment: In the first method, `stack` is written lowercase. In the second method, you call the constructor of `Stack` with an int, but that constructor is not defined.

Comment: The second test method does not really test anything, it has not assertion...

Comment: @deHaar ensuring that something happens without an exception is an assertion of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
//returns and removes the top element of the stack
public T pop() {
    return stack.get(stack.size()-1);
}
```

You don't remove the element, use remove instead of get

Other errors:

```
void isEmpty() {
    //Typo errors here, s is uppercase and missing parenthesis
    stack s = new stack<Integer>;
    assertEquals(true, s.isEmpty());
}

@Test
void peek() {
    //What does Stack(1) mean? There is no such constructor in class
    Stack t = new Stack(1);
}
```

Also:

```
//If you already extend Vector you don't need a Vector field for the data
class Stack<T> extends Vector<T> {
    private Vector<T> stack;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those corrections make a lot of sense. Using Stack(1) I tried to create a stack with the number 1 already on it. But I think void push() {
        Stack t = new Stack();
        t.push(1);
        assertEquals(false, t.isEmpty());
    } works better. Thanks for your reply!